# Multiple-step OLE DB Operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB Status Value

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Please help me. Excel VBA is throwing this error: Multiple-step OLE DB Operation generated errors

on the line : cmd.Parameters("[days]") = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MABI_Extracts").Range("B18").Value

I'm trying to run a query in access named "AGBA_Conversion" with an integer parameter. How do I resolve? thanks in advance :)

```
Sub RECT_MBTCLeads2_Extracts()
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim b As String
Dim d As Long
Dim a As String

 
Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AGBA_Conversion")
sht.Range("B1").ClearContents

 


cmd.ActiveConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\nemberga\OneDrive - AXA\Documents\Automation\MBTC Conversion.accdb"

 

cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = "AGBA_Conversion"  '<<<--here is where you write your query sql
cmd.Parameters("[days]") = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MABI_Extracts").Range("B18").Value

 

Options = adCmdTable
Set rs = cmd.Execute
sht.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs  '--bulk copy to the Excel sheet
rs.Close
cmd.ActiveConnection.Close

   
    
    MsgBox "All data were  successfully retrieved from the queries!", vbInformation, "Done"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: First [create the parameter](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_comm_createparameter.asp), then add it to the parameters collection.

Comment: how will I do it? I'm new to this sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters is a collection of Parameter. You need first to create the object using CreateParameter, then to add it to the collection using Append.

Replace

```
cmd.Parameters("[days]") = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MABI_Extracts").Range("B18").Value
```

By

```
Dim p
Set p = cmd.CreateParameter("days", adInteger, adParamInput)
p.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MABI_Extracts").Range("B18").Value
cmd.Parameters.Append p
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/append-and-createparameter-methods-example-vb?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: English page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/command-object-parameters

Comment: Thank you!! this was very helpful. I was able to run the vba perfectly :)